# About Themes of Ubuntu

Tags: themes

Before installing a theme, I would like to know what does a theme actually change? I can still change my wallpaper right? But the screenshots I see of themes seem different in that. For example, one theme had a light-blue wallpaper and so all its windows and dialogues were light-blue. Does it mean the theme is set to light-blue and has an uneditable wallpapers package?

Further, by Unity Tweak Tool and other tools, I can change the colour schemes, etc. So what's the use of a theme anyway?

Comment: Which themes do you mean? GTK+ or Icon themes? You can change your wallpaper with both themes. [This](http://imgur.com/W7yZKPR) is my desktop. An icon theme changes the themes in the Top panel and on the Launcher, where as a GTK theme changes the window decoration and drop down menus and such.

Comment: Hmm thanks. I think I meant a GTK+ theme not an icon theme.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See @Jbuch14 comment he explained it nicely and theme won't change wallpaper you have to set the wallpaper manually. As you asked they won't come with uneditable wallpapers package you can change your wallpapers. In your example what they did is set a gtk theme first which changes window decorations to light-blue and after that manually kept a matching light-blue wallpaper.

Comment: Oh I see. So I can add a GTK theme to change window decorations, etc and still nothing is changed except, well, window decorations. That's cool.